# How do I edit .json data with python?

Tags: python, json

So I'm making a Discord bot and I need to edit some data in my .json file

Here's the json file:

[image]

"name"'s variable is player

I want to edit the balance, there's gonna be a command to add and subtract, so how do I do that?

I tried writing and deleting it, but either I did it wrong or it doesn't work

Comment: Show us how you did it.  All you need to do is `json.loads` to convert this to a Python structure, then use regular Python code to make your change, then `json.dumps` to write it back out.

Comment: I suppose in this case json.dump and json.load are better choiches, since there is JSON as a file instead of as a string. But yes, the OP just has to read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Python as a built-in module called `json`, that provides a `json.JSONDecoder` and a `json.JSONEncoder` class, a `JSON` (`JavaScript Object Notation`) parser (`json.loads`) and few other functions.

---

If you have your `data.json` file, you can convert it to Python...

```
import json
with open("data.json", 'r+') as file:
    my_data = json.load(file)
```

...edit it...

```
my_data["Key"] = "New Value"
```

...and encode it back

```
json.dump(my_data, file)
```

Comment: I added this, and now what it does is add a fully new one:

[
 {
  "name": "name"
  "balance": 0.0
 }
][{"name": "name", "balance": 10}]

Is there a way to delete the old one and add the new one to the same set, or just update the new one?

Comment: I've been working for years with python's json module and it has never given me problems... can you edit your answer with the results you got?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/bJG7RZj

A link to an image of everything

Comment: Maybe because you appended (I mean APPENDED and not overwrited) a dictionary to data?

Comment: So how would I overwrite it?

Comment: instead of data.append you do data=